# Where Else Would the Cretaceous Comet Hit?

Tags: apocalypse, geology

Over 65 million years ago, a comet the size of Mount Everest slammed into Mexico's Yucatán Peninsula, reducing the mighty Dinosaur Empire, which had endured for 150 million years, into ruin.

[image: Map showing impact crater in the Yucatan and Gulf of Mexico]

Chicxulub proved to make a horrible point for ground zero, not because there was water involved, meaning tsumanis large enough to make the 2004 Indonesia catastrophe mere child's play, but because the rocks were high in sulfur.  Which means that when the bomb hit, the vaporized rock released the sulfur into the atmosphere, driving the global climate into chaos.

So let's say that the comet landed instead on any one of these spots:

**Vredefort, South Africa**

[image: Map showing alternative impact site where Vredefort and Parys are now]

**Popigai, Russia**

[image: Map showing alternative impact site; entirely on land]

**Acraman, South Australia**

[image: Map showing alternative impact site at Lake Acraman]

If the comet landed on any one of these three sites instead of Chicxulub, would the Mesozoic-Cenozoic Extinction event be identical to OTL, or would it have acted differently?

Comment: We can probably provide some facts & physics as an answer but I think the ultimate interpretation of the results will be opinion based.

Comment: Start by doing some research of your own. You've accepted the "sulfuric acid amplification" theory. So what kind of rocks constitute your proposed alternative sites?

Comment: Ultimately, what killed the dinosaurs?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast  Really?  Back to the wave of dismissal again?

Comment: To give this answer its due will require a lot of research and sifting of the facts.  Current theory (as I understand it) is that the Chicxulub impact may NOT have been the Dinosaurs "nail in the coffin" but merely accelerated their eventual demise.  There were other things going on (e.g. massive volcanism) and probably a reduction in available atmospheric oxygen.  Trying to weigh the relative effects of each of these is going to take tons of work and in the end be opinion based.  I think the question is interesting but I'm not willing to sink that much work into figuring it out.

Comment: @JohnWDailey - No, I'm just asking you to do some basic research before you ask us to do it for you. What kind of rocks make up your alternate sites, and how do those rock types differ from the Yucatan Peninsula?

Comment: @Jim2B  The other factors of the Cretaceous extinction event are not relevant in this question.

Comment: It is formerly know as the Chicxulub Impactor and was not at all a comet , Just so you know

Comment: @TheoclesofSaturn  http://www.livescience.com/28127-dinosaur-extinction-caused-by-comet.html

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this, for a couple of reasons. My main one is I think this should be three questions, each saying "what would the effects be if instead of whatever extinction event you think instead was a giant comet hitting X location? That might improve the scope of your answer, and reducing the opinionated part of it.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon  You're not making sense.

Comment: Split into three questions, one for each location. Then replace whatever extinction even happened with a comet hitting those locations.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon  You want me to get docked for duplication?

Comment: I would argue that somewhere in the ocean makes for a better impact site, not worse. While water is not going to stop or slow down the asteroid/comet, it may drag the ejected dust and rocks. Requires a rigorous calculation though. Maybe evaporation is so fast that effect is just the same as hitting dry ground.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by duplication, but if it already has an answer on another question, than there is no need to ask a new one about it.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon  You told me to cut this question into three questions.  That is ASKING to be docked for duplication.

Comment: Not if they are different locations, with different compositions. If you are really that concerned about it, however, you can ask on the meta.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.radiolab.org/story/dinopocalypse/ (or the video version [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K52vD4WBdLw)) which suggests that **the specific location of the impact**, especially among the options you've proposed, **was not all that important**.  The debris/rock vapor rebounding back to space crystallized into little bits and Earth's gravity pulled many of those little bits of rock back in.  As they came in, many of them burned up in the atmosphere, each adding a tiny bit of heat to the atmosphere, but because there are so many of them it was a LOT of heat in the atmosphere, getting up to the temperature of a pizza oven, enough to cook dinos but not the small mammals who happened to be sufficiently far underground at the time.